# Oracle: separate column histograms for partitions

Tags: oracle, performance, statistics

I have a partitioned table like `MY_TABLE(PART_KEY, DATE_KEY, ...)` with a local partitioned index on `(PART_KEY, DATE_KEY)`.  When I collect stats on the table, I end up with a HEIGHT BALANCED histogram on DATE_KEY.

The issue: the DATE_KEY values are not uniformly distributed in each partition, and the buckets in ALL_TAB_HISTOGRAMS look like they reflect the distribution of values across the whole table.

The question: If I am running a query like `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE PART_KEY=x and DATE_KEY between y and z` is there a way I ensure that the optimizer will use a histogram reflecting the distribution of values for the specific partition?

Otherwise, what I think is happening is that the global distribution makes certain ranges of values look more selective than they really are, given that the query will only hit a single partition.

Comment: `dba_tab_histograms` (or `all_tab_histograms`) will have the table-level histograms.  It sounds like you're saying those are correct.  `dba_part_histograms` will have the partition-level histograms.  Are those values accurate?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.  can't believe I missed it.  I think there's my problem - global histogram but none for the partition.